# Sendmail not working on command line, connection refused by smart host

Tags: ubuntu, sendmail

I am attempting to set up sendmail to eventually be used by a Django/python application which will reside on the same server (a Digital Ocean droplet), however, before I try to get it to work in python I would like to test it on the command line.

I used this tutorial to set it up: https://www.cloudbooklet.com/how-to-install-and-setup-sendmail-on-ubuntu/, but if that link goes away here are the commands I ran to set it up so far:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install sendmail
sudo vim /etc/hosts 
  (added my domain 'prosaurus' to the 127.0.0.1 line after localhost
sudo mkdir /etc/mail/authinfo
udo chmod -R 700 /etc/mail/authinfo
cd /etc/mail/authinfo
sudo vim smtp-auth 
  (added: AuthInfo: "U:root" "I:email-address" "P:password") with my info
sudo makemap hash smtp-auth < smtp-auth
cd /etc/mail
sudo vim sendmail.mc
Added all of this:
  define(`SMART_HOST',`[smtp.prosaurus.com]')dnl
  define(`RELAY_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 587')dnl
  define(`ESMTP_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 587')dnl
  define(`confAUTH_OPTIONS', `A p')dnl
  TRUST_AUTH_MECH(`EXTERNAL DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
  define(`confAUTH_MECHANISMS', `EXTERNAL GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
  FEATURE(`authinfo',`hash -o /etc/mail/authinfo/smtp-auth.db')dnl
cd /etc/mail
make
sudo /etc/init.d/sendmail restart
```

Note: I stopped the tutorial when it got to the PHP section since I'm not using PHP. The next thing I did was try to use sendmail on the command line with this command:

```
echo "Subject: sendmail test" | sendmail -v myemail@whatever.com
```

The response I get is this:

```
WARNING: local host name (ubuntu-myserverinfo) is not qualified; see cf/README: WHO AM I?
myemail@whatever.com... Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay...
220 ubuntu-myserverinfo ESMTP Sendmail 8.15.2/8.15.2/Debian-22ubuntu3; Tue, 27 Sep 2022 21:37:07 GMT; (No UCE/UBE) logging access from: localhost(OK)-localhost [127.0.0.1]
>>> EHLO ubuntu-myserverinfo
250-ubuntu-myserverinfo Hello localhost [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-EXPN
250-VERB
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE
250-DSN
250-ETRN
250-AUTH DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
>>> VERB
250 2.0.0 Verbose mode
>>> MAIL From:<myuser@ubuntu-myserver> SIZE=23 AUTH=myuser@ubuntu-myserver
250 2.1.0 <myuser@ubuntu-myserver>... Sender ok
>>> RCPT To:<myemail@whatever.com>
>>> DATA
250 2.1.5 <myemail@whatever.com>... Recipient ok
354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
>>> .
050 <myemail@whatever.com>... Connecting to smtp.prosaurus.com. port 587 via relay...
050 <myemail@whatever.com>... Deferred: Connection refused by smtp.prosaurus.com.
250 2.0.0 28RLb7KM022677 Message accepted for delivery
myemail@whatever.com... Sent (28RLb7KM022677 Message accepted for delivery)
Closing connection to [127.0.0.1]
>>> QUIT
221 2.0.0 ubuntu-myserver closing connection
```

Note: personal info removed from messages

Any ideas what I missed?

Addendum...

I think I may not fully understand what is involved in sending email.  This is an attempt to explain my situation.

1. I have only one server.  This server has my python code on it.  This server is the destination from my website.  All DNS records point to this server
2. I have installed sendmail on this server per the tutorial and commands listed.  I am not using any other email server.  My goal is to set up a single server as my email server.
3. I have configured sendmail myself.  it points to smtp.mysite.com.  This seems weird to me that the server would have to reach out to itself to send email.  It seems like maybe a typical setup actually involves multiple servers and I'm doing something wrong by having it all on the same machine.
4. I have not installed a mail server (other than sendmail) on this machine.  perhaps this is what is missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your local sendmail is configured to use smart host.
Configure smart host refused TCP-SMTP connection from you local sendmail.

```
>>> VERB
[…]
050 <myemail@whatever.com>... Connecting to smtp.prosaurus.com. port 587 via relay...
050 <myemail@whatever.com>... Deferred: Connection refused by smtp.prosaurus.com.
```

**Conduct the final test**:  Try to get SMTP greeting message from your host using `telnet` program.

```
telnet smtp.prosaurus.com 587
```

Can you ctelnet SMTP (25) or SMTPS (465) on the smart host?
[ Classic telnet will not get SMTP greeting on SMTPS (465) port because it does not support encryption ]

Comment: question: "smart host" is that sendmail?  (i am still confused if i need something more than just smartmail installed, is smartmail the email server or is there something else also?) Note also, I tried the telnet command you posted and it says connection refused.  This system doesn't seem to have ctelnet command

Comment: Your local sendmail is configured to send all outgoing mail via smart host (another SMTP server at smtp.prosaurus.com:587).  1) Is it proper configuration? 2) Is it a temporary problem? [overzealous firewall or remote server down] 3) Can you use another smart host or no smart host? [Is your sendmail at fixed/permanent IP address?]

Comment: ok, your comment here is making me think that I have a basic misunderstanding of how this all works.  You say there is another smtp server?  Is sendmail not an smtp server?  please refer to the tutorial i posted above and realize I am starting with absolutely no knowledge of how email works.  The only thing i have done is what that tutorial and this question state.

Comment: I added some more detail to my post.  perhaps this will explain